# Find columns with percentage values in dataframe and convert the values to numeric while changing the column name

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and some columns incluse percentages. I would like to find those columns and delete `"%"` in order to convert them to numeric values. Also I would like to add the `"_percentage"` in the relative column names. My dataframe:

```
name<-c("asd","sff","edf")
growth<-c("0.89%","0.99%","0.59%")
no<-c(3,4,5)
change<-c("0.67%","0.45%","0.59%")
df<-data.frame(name,growth,no,change)
```

and I want it to be like:

```
name growth_percentage no change_percentage
1  asd              0.89  3              0.67
2  sff              0.99  4              0.45
3  edf              0.59  5              0.59
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(~any(grepl('%', .))), 
                readr::parse_number, .names = '{col}_percentage')) %>%
  select(-where(~any(grepl('%', .))))

#  name no growth_percentage change_percentage
#1  asd  3              0.89              0.67
#2  sff  4              0.99              0.45
#3  edf  5              0.59              0.59
```

`any(grepl())` returns the columns which has atleast one value of `'%'`, `parse_number` removes any non-numeric character and converts it into numeric.

Comment: I get: x is.character(x) is not TRUE
i Input `..1` is `across(where(~any(grepl("%", .))), readr::parse_number, .names = "{col}_percentage")`

Comment: It seems you are on R < 4.0.0. Try with `df<-data.frame(name,growth,no,change, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: if I would like to keep column names as they are what should I do?

Comment: Remove the `.names = '{col}_percentage'` and `select` from the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this:

```
cols <- names(which(apply(df, 2, function(x) any(grepl("%", x)))))
cols_percentage <- unlist(paste0(cols, "_percentage"))
setDT(df)
df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) str_remove(x, "%")), .SDcols = cols]
setnames(df, cols, cols_percentage)
```